# generate random float number ranging [0,1] in c

Tags: c, random, srand

When I used `rand()` with `srand()` to generate random number in [0,1], it gave me numbers like: 0.70324, 0.70328, 0.70321...

They were difference only in the last one or two digits, while I was intended to get random float numbers like 0.1,0.7,0.3....

How could I get random float number like that instead of making difference in the last digit?

Here's my code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    float randomNum;
    for (  i=0; i<10; i++){
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
        randomNum = ((float)rand())/RAND_MAX;
        printf("%f\n",randomNum);
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Move `srand` outside the loop. Call it once, at the start of a program. You keep resetting the RNG, with one second granularity.

Comment: Side note:  Rarely have I seen the need for the range `[0.0 to 1.0]`, but the range `[0.0 1.0)`  (Upper end does not include 1.0)

Comment: Note: with typical 32-bit `int` and 32-bit `float`, `((float)rand())/RAND_MAX;`  will not provide an equal occurrence of `float` values.  `1.0f` will occur 64 times as often as  `0.0f` due to rounding of `(float)rand()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should call `srand()` only once, at the beginning of your program. Calling it before each call to `rand()` only makes the results more predictable, since each time you call it with a number probably very similar to the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

Move the line

```
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
```

to the start of the program i.e. just after `main`.

You only need to seed the random number generator once.

Answer (score 2):

`srand()` only initializes the pseudo-random number generator using a piece of data given to it, called the seed. The `rand()` function then uses this seed to produce random numbers. Afterwards, each call to `rand()` is based on the previous random number that was generated. You are not intended to call `srand()` more than once anyway. (You can actually see this behavior in one of [rand's implementation](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/invisible/src/crt/rand.c.htm))

The problem here is that `time()` gives you the current time in *seconds*, so when you initialize the generator and call `rand()` every time you will get the same number, until one second will pass.